# How to insert text into the node that made by raphaeljs?

Tags: javascript, raphael

How to insert text into the node that made by raphaeljs?
I want to use onClick to call the function u insert or edit text on the node.
but I don't know how to do that.
please help me.

image: http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Use this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/)**.

It is using your example with text inserted.

```
    connections = [],
    shapes = [  r.ellipse(190, 100, 30, 20),
                r.rect(290, 80, 60, 40, 10),
                r.rect(290, 180, 60, 40, 2),
                r.ellipse(450, 100, 20, 20)
            ],
    texts = [   r.text(190, 100, "One"),
                r.text(320, 100, "Two"),
                r.text(320, 200, "Three"),
                r.text(450, 100, "Four")
            ];
```

**This is exactly what you need.**